# Add wrapping tags for each child tags - XSL transformation

Tags: xml, xslt

I have following xml structure;

```
           <urn:SERIALS>
              <urn:SERIAL_NO>TH66</urn:SERIAL_NO>
              <urn:SERIAL_NO>TH95</urn:SERIAL_NO>
              <urn:SERIAL_NO>TH71</urn:SERIAL_NO>
           </urn:SERIALS>
```

I need to convert this to following (adding extra `<urn:SERIAL_NOS>` wrapper to each `<urn:SERIAL_NO>`);

```
           <urn:SERIALS>
              <urn:SERIAL_NOS>
                 <urn:SERIAL_NO>TH66</urn:SERIAL_NO>
              </urn:SERIAL_NOS>
              <urn:SERIAL_NOS>
                 <urn:SERIAL_NO>TH95</urn:SERIAL_NO>
              </urn:SERIAL_NOS>
              <urn:SERIAL_NOS>
                 <urn:SERIAL_NO>TH71</urn:SERIAL_NO>
              <urn:SERIAL_NOS>
           </urn:SERIALS>
```

I tried following XSL code...

```
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()" name="ident">
  <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="urn:SERIAL_NO">
  <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
  <urn:SERIAL_NOS>
    <xsl:call-template name="ident" />
  </urn:SERIAL_NOS>
  </xsl:template>
```

Output result is bit weird... It has the value of the Serials infront of `<urn:SERIAL_NOS>` tag

```
           <urn:SERIALS>
                 TH66<urn:SERIAL_NOS>
                 <urn:SERIAL_NO>TH66</urn:SERIAL_NO>
              </urn:SERIAL_NOS>
                 TH95<urn:SERIAL_NOS>
                 <urn:SERIAL_NO>TH95</urn:SERIAL_NO>
              </urn:SERIAL_NOS>
                 TH71<urn:SERIAL_NOS>
                 <urn:SERIAL_NO>TH71</urn:SERIAL_NO>
              </urn:SERIAL_NOS>
           </urn:SERIALS>
```

Even I removed the  `<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>`, then it appears blank spaces replacing the 'TH' values. Any idea how to solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The second template should simply be

```
  <xsl:template match="urn:SERIAL_NO">
  <urn:SERIAL_NOS>
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  </urn:SERIAL_NOS>
  </xsl:template>
```